# Is it possible to restrict a route for AJAX only?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

Is it possible to restrict a Symfony 2 route for XHR requests only? I want to declare routes, which are only accessible via AJAX.

I do not want to put some extra lines into each AJAX-specific-actions like that:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

I want to define:

- one rule for AJAX requests
- one rule for GET/POST requests to the same URL

in order to get around having conditions like above.

Comment: Why? The data they expose won't be available to anyone who couldn't get at it anyway.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Want to restrict access to the route only for XHR requests.

Comment: @crudolf — If someone (or two people) ask you **why** you want to do X, then just repeating that you want to do X is not helpful.

Comment: @Quentin -- thanks. I have added a reason, why I am asking the question.

Comment: @crudolf — My question was "Why are you trying to restrict access?" not "Why use routes to do it?"

Comment: @Quentin -- I have updated the question. I guess you will not be confident. The application needs to behave differently for AJAX and general a browser request. It is obviously not for security reasons.

Comment: @Quentin -- the question was "is it possible.." - so if it's not directly supported from the framework, it's also an answer.

Comment: @crudolf "It is obviously not for security reasons" Would this be a bad thing to use this for security reasons (so that only the same domain JS app could access the route)?

Comment: JQuery HTTP headers can be spoofed, so there is no security gain by adding those rules.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I know this question is a bit older but meanwhile a **new way** to achieve this was introduced **in Symfony 2.4**.

[Matching Expressions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#matching-expressions)

For an ajax restriction it would look like this:

```
contact:
    path:     /contact
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:contact }
    condition: "request.isXmlHttpRequest()"
```

Also possible in Annotation:

```
/**
 * ContactAction
 *
 * @Route("/contact", name="contact", condition="request.isXmlHttpRequest()")
 */
```

Comment: I think you mean `XMLHttpRequest`, with XML capitalized.

Comment: You can also use simply `request.isXmlHttpRequest()` on condition to make it working.

Comment: **UPDATE:** the documentation link for  *"Completely Customized Route Matching with Conditions"* has been renamed, and is now reachable at https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/routing.html#matching-expressions

Answer (score 10):

My advice would be to define your own router service instead of [default](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Routing/Router.php), which would extend from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router`, and redefine method [resolveParameters()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Routing/Router.php#L84) with implementing your own logic for handling additional requirements.

And then, you could do something like this in your routing:

```
your_route:
    pattern:  /somepattern
    defaults: { somedefaults }
    requirements:
        _request_type:  some_requirement
```

Comment: This sounds really good. How performance relevant is it? Is the Default Routing Service really that Poorly implemented? I think i give it a try.

Comment: Well... Poorly or not, it is implemented :) And the best thing about Symfony2 is that you can redefine services and extend basic controllers with whatever functionality ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that you can prevent the request taking place, however you can check for an XHR request in the Controller by checking the current Request

The code would look like this:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    // ...
}
```

This is not 100% reliable, due to among other things, browser inconsistencies and the possibility of proxy interference. However it is the predominant method of checking for an asynchronous request and is recommended by many. If you are cr

**URL Parameter**

An alternative would be to add a parameter in your URL to identify the request as asynchronous. This is achieved by adding `?ajax=1` to your URL. Then, check for the parameter with:

```
$AjaxRequest = $request->getParameter('ajax');
If($AjaxRequest == 1) {
    //...
}
```

Of course, at this point you could also create a specific Route e.g. `/ajax/index/`.

Comment: Instead of using `>` for code highlighting, you should use 4 spaces or `.

Comment: @j0k Thanks, will remember that.

Comment: isXmlHttpRequest is not reliable.

Comment: That's the way I do it currently. But I want to remove this piece of code from those actions.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for highlighting that. I've updated my answer with a little more explination on reliability.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. It is not depend on which framework you are using, AJAX requests basically are just requests to a server. There is no 100% reliable solution, just "hacks".

Comment: On the server side of a specific application i know which client side JavaScript Library is being used. Therefore it is not a hack, if i require a specific http header field for specific routes.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for does not exist in Symfony routing configuration.

Request::isXmlHttpRequest is even not 100% reliable, and checks HTTP headers put by your JavaScript library :

> It works if your JavaScript library set an X-Requested-With HTTP header.
>   It is known to work with Prototype, Mootools, jQuery.

Comment: If I know, that my cilent side library is a specific one, then this method will be 100% reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [requirements](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) for reach the described result.
So, suppose that you're defining routes onto yml format, you have to do something like this

```
my_route:
  pattern:  /path/to/route
  defaults: { _controller: CompanyBundle:Controller:Action, _format: html }
  requirements:
      _format:  xmlhttp /* not sure about the correct format because
                           i've never checked about */
```

And you can, of course, use `_method:  POST` or `_method:  GET`

Comment: This is what I am searching for. But what is the concrete value name?

Comment: @crudolf documentation about is very, very, poor. I suggest to start with the parameter i suggest you and, then, to try something like "xml" or "ajax" directly. Now I'am not currently onto a machine that permitt me to do this kind of try.