# Check User Interface on route

Tags: symfony

***I have different user types:***

1. **"UserOne"** type implements the "UserOne" interface
2. **"UserTwo"** type implements the "UserTwo" interface

However, they have the same role **`ROLE_USER`**.

They can do different actions.

How can I make sure that **`UserOne`** can only access to `app.php/userone/etc...` without checking this in each controller **`if User implements UserOne`**? From what I know, we can only use roles in the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redefine the router service for [resolving parameters](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Routing/Router.php#L84).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11663641/970721) may be useful for you

Answer (score 2):

if they can do different actions, they must play differents role. Declare two roles in security settings