# Symfony 2.3., How to restrict a route for ajax call only

Tags: php, ajax, symfony-2.3

I am a newbie to Symfony 2. I am using Symfony 2.3.

I am using yml files for my routes. I want a certain route to be restricted for Ajax call only. How can I achieve that? I have found one similar  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557658/is-it-possible-to-restrict-a-route-for-ajax-only) but the solution it suggested is for Symfony 2.4

So please help me how can I achieve it.

Currently I have written conditional code in my controller ajax action something like below, but I do not know how to handle if the call to that route is not through Ajax.

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
   // Some operations    
   // Prepare the data array based on the Ajax request.
}

return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Ajax:index.html.twig', array('data' =>  $data));
```

I want that this route can be accessed only with Ajax else it should throw some exception like invalid route or redirect to some other page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know such a way in symfony 2.3 but in the version 2.4, the below routing configuration can be used to identify ajax requests.

```
ajax_route:
    path:     /your-ajax-route
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Ajax:index }
    condition: "request.isXmlHttpRequest()"
```

Annotation version of routing can also be used like the following:

```
/**
 * IndexAction
 *
 * @Route("/your-ajax-route/", name="ajax_route", condition="request.isXmlHttpRequest()")
 */
```

All the above is only a temporary solution for understanding the ajax request otherwise the headers can be manipulated and you never can identify if the request is xmlhttp. There is no 100% sure way to check the xml http request.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, Headers can be manipulated. so a curl request with bunch of headers can pull an ajax request. I believe you can check the headers with Symfony 2.3

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

---

```
$ajax = $request->headers->get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH');
if($ajax != 'xmlhttprequest'){
 throw new \Exception("This is not an ajax request");
}
```

or you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "xmlhttprequest"`

Comment: call of $request->server->get is compliant with symfony2 recommendations. it s better than $_SERVER